# How to hide column of devexpress XtraGrid

Tags: c#, devexpress, hide, xtragrid

Hai all,
    Am using devexpress XtraGrid in C#.NET application.On run time i want to hide 1 column of XtraGrid and access that column in code behind page.And please help to access rows and columns of
XtraGrid.

Thank You

Comment: http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_Visibletopic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the `View.Columns[someFieldName].Visible` property to hide / show a column.  Please also refer to the following topic:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument753

Answer (score 10):

To hide a column from user set columns visible property to False as mentioned above.

However this puts the hidden column in SelectColumn Menu which user can access at run time.

Right Click Grid Header -> Click Select Columns -> Choose hidden column from small window -> Drag it to the Grid.

In this case your hidden columns will be available to user. There are two possible solutions to avoid above Situation:

1. In Addition to setting visible property of **Column** also set **OptionColumn.AllowShowHide** to **False**. This will make sure that this column will not Pop up in column select window.
2. Other solution should be used only when you want to give absolutely no right to the user for changing the layout of the grid. This can be done by Setting **GridView**'s property - **OptionMenu->EnableColumnMenu** to **False**. 
   However after setting this user will be restricted from all other layout Options also like Groupping, filter, search etc.

Comment: Do you know how to set AllowShowHide for a treelist?

Comment: Hi..never used Treelist but this might help you: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument326 Seems like it can be done with something like this: TreeListOptionsColumn.ShowInCustomizationForm property.

Comment: The thing that was stumping me is you have to use fieldName.  I was trying to use the name of the column and kept getting  NULL back

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `ColumnName.Visible=False;`

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I did this to indefinitely hide ALL my xtraGrid columns so I can select the few I can show (make visible true).

```
        int myCount;
        try { myCount = this.gridView2.Columns.Count; }
        catch { myCount = 0; }

        for (int j = 0; j < myCount; j++)
        {
            this.gridView2.Columns[j].Visible = false;
        }
```

Hope it helps.