# How to access Columns for DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl in C#

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

I try to get the ColumnNames and the current Vieworder of my GridControl.
The docu won't help me an the ".Net Reflector"-Tool also won't give me advice.

The tip from an other stackoverflowpost ( [How to hide column of devexpress XtraGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615415/how-to-hide-column-of-devexpress-xtragrid) ) also won't help me, because, i can't access View.Columns

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest you are trying to use property gridControl.MainView to access a view. This property is of type BaseView (base class for all views) so in order to access columns/order information you should cast it to GridView (or whatever type you are using):

```
var firstColumnName = ((GridView)gridControl.MainView).Columns[0].FieldName;
```

Comment: A little irritated at the hidden ways to get at some of the events and properties of DevEx controls. But +1 for you ...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't populated the column collection , there will be no column to access.

This is something that you'll usually do while you are designing the grid.

Run designer -> Columns -> Retrieve Fields.

Comment: Sorry for my late (realy late!) reply, but i wasn't the developer, i had to develop a test tool and had no access to the source code.